# unlock specific area in a protected excel sheet with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have to unlock a specific range *(D6:BC116)* in a excel sheet. It should be able for other people editing this specific area. So it should be unlocked for them.
At first I manually protect the whole sheet without any code. And after that I want to unprotect the specific area for editing. But something always goes wrong. I have these two codes. The first code has the hidden property it only hides empty cells. The other code I am trying to unprotect specific area I want to edit after protecting the whole sheet.
I am not really sure if the problem is in the first code because of the hidden property? And I am not sure if they are in a relation?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 For Each cell In Range("B6:B112")
 If cell.Value <> "" Then
 cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Else
 cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
 Next cell
End Sub

Sub UnlockCells()

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6:BC116").Locked = False
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect

End Sub
```

And when I execute this I always get **"Index out of range"**

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: I get the error at _cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False_ and I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to unprotect before unlocking.
Like this:

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
 .Unprotect "MyLongAndSecurePassword"
 .Range("D6:BC116").Locked = False
 .Protect
 End with
```

Concerning the first part of the code - make sure that you use a variable, which is not named `cell`, because `cell` is used by the VBEditor. Name your variable `rngCell`, `myCell` or anything else but `cell`. And declare it like this: `Dim rngCell as Range`.

Last point - lock your worksheet and try to hide and unhide manually the rows. Is it possible? If not, you know the reason for the error.

**Edit:**

To check whether the sheet is protected, try this in the *Worksheet_Change*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").ProtectContents Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In Range("B6:B112")
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: my tablename is "Tabelle1" but I get an error again "index out of range"

Comment: here is the error _cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False_ really don't know why

Comment: Have you tried the 3 solutions in my answer? @flowers1234 If you worksheet is named `Tabelle1` - this is the name you should be using in the code.

Comment: .Range("D6:BC116").Locked = False ? yes I have. But it does not work.

Comment: I think the problem occurs with **entireRow**

Comment: Yes. My Code with worksheet change .. is only necessary for the unprotected mode. When I protect the file I get the error because of the **Worksheet_Change** but I only want the hide function when the sheet is unprotected ! Can I solve this???

Comment: @flowers1234 - now I get it... Its doable, yes

Comment: I can't understand this. I get index out of range :/ My table name is "Tabelle1" at the left of VBA there are all my tables named _Tabelle 1 (Costs)_ what's wrong there :(

Comment: Ok. If your table is named `Tabelle1`, then rename `Sheet1` to `Tabelle1` everywhere in your code. Why are you using `Sheet1` anyway?

Comment: It's a german version. They are all named Tabelle 1 , Tabelle 2 and so on. And I have only this code for Tabelle1 don't now where to change else

Comment: I am so sorry I think the name in the brackets is the worksheet name and not Tabelle1, right?

Comment: @flowers1234 - congrats! :)